# Easy way to do nd-array contraction using advanced indexing in Python

Tags: arrays, numpy, advanced-indexing

I know there must be an elegant way to do this using advanced indexing, I just can't figure it out.

Suppose I have the (2,3,4) array

```
x = array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

and the (4,) array `y = array([1,0,1,1])`

What is the most elegant way to obtain the (3,4) array that

```
z = np.zeros((3,4))
for ii in xrange(3):
    for jj in xrange(4):
         z[ii,jj] = x[y[jj],ii,jj]
```

produces?

Comment: What's `kk` in your iteration?  Show the desired (3,4) result

Comment: `jj` can't index the middle dim of `x`

Comment: `x[y, :, np.arange(4)].T` might work

Comment: sorry @hpaulj accidentally left over when I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [490]: x[y,:,np.arange(4)]                                                                  
Out[490]: 
array([[12, 16, 20],
       [ 1,  5,  9],
       [14, 18, 22],
       [15, 19, 23]])
```

We need to transpose this.  With a mix of basic and advanced indexing, the slice dimension has been put last:

```
In [491]: x[y,:,np.arange(4)].T                                                                
Out[491]: 
array([[12,  1, 14, 15],
       [16,  5, 18, 19],
       [20,  9, 22, 23]])
```

(that basic/advanced quirk is documented and discussed in some SO.)

or with advanced indexing all around:

```
In [492]: x[y,np.arange(3)[:,None],np.arange(4)]                                               
Out[492]: 
array([[12,  1, 14, 15],
       [16,  5, 18, 19],
       [20,  9, 22, 23]])
```