# Vectorized way to contract Numpy array using advanced indexing

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, array-broadcasting, numpy-indexing

I have a Numpy array of dimensions (d1,d2,d3,d4), for instance `A = np.arange(120).reshape((2,3,4,5))`.
I would like to contract it so as to obtain `B` of dimensions (d1,d2,d4).
The d3-indices of parts to pick are collected in an indexing array `Idx` of dimensions (d1,d2).
`Idx` provides, for each couple *(x1,x2)* of indices along (d1,d2), the index *x3* for which `B` should retain the whole corresponding d4-line in `A`, for example `Idx = rng.integers(4, size=(2,3))`.

To sum up, for all *(x1,x2)*, I want `B[x1,x2,:] = A[x1,x2,Idx[x1,x2],:]`.

Is there an efficient, vectorized way to do that, without using a loop? I'm aware that this is similar to [Easy way to do nd-array contraction using advanced indexing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861676/easy-way-to-do-nd-array-contraction-using-advanced-indexing-in-python) but I have trouble extending the solution to higher dimensional arrays.

MWE

```
A = np.arange(120).reshape((2,3,4,5))
Idx = rng.integers(4, size=(2,3))

# correct result:
B = np.zeros((2,3,5))
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        B[i,j,:] = A[i,j,Idx[i,j],:]

# what I would like, which doesn't work:
B = A[:,:,Idx[:,:],:]
```

Comment: Sorry but didn't get what is wrong with your current approach? Please provide a minimal working example

Comment: try something like `A[np.arange(2)]:,None], np.arange(3), Idx]`.  That is a pair of `arange` arrays that broadcast with `idx`.

Comment: Are your array so small in practice? Numpy will have a pretty high overhead in that case, even once vectorized.

Comment: No, the arrays I'm working with are much bigger and involve more dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Times for 3 alternatives:

```
In [91]: %%timeit
    ...: B = np.zeros((2,3,5),A.dtype)
    ...: for i in range(2):
    ...:     for j in range(3):
    ...:         B[i,j,:] = A[i,j,Idx[i,j],:]
    ...: 

11 µs ± 48.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [92]: timeit A[np.arange(2)[:,None],np.arange(3),Idx]
8.58 µs ± 44 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [94]: timeit np.squeeze(np.take_along_axis(A, Idx[:,:,None,None], axis=2), axis=2)
29.4 µs ± 448 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Relative times may differ with larger arrays.  But this is a good size for testing the correctness.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that is `np.squeeze(np.take_along_axis(A, Idx[:,:,None,None], axis=2), axis=2)`.

For example,

```
In [49]: A = np.arange(120).reshape(2, 3, 4, 5)

In [50]: rng = np.random.default_rng(0xeeeeeeeeeee)

In [51]: Idx = rng.integers(4, size=(2,3))

In [52]: Idx
Out[52]: 
array([[2, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 1]])

In [53]: C = np.squeeze(np.take_along_axis(A, Idx[:,:,None,None], axis=2), axis=2)

In [54]: C
Out[54]: 
array([[[ 10,  11,  12,  13,  14],
        [ 20,  21,  22,  23,  24],
        [ 45,  46,  47,  48,  49]],

       [[ 60,  61,  62,  63,  64],
        [ 90,  91,  92,  93,  94],
        [105, 106, 107, 108, 109]]])
```

Check the known correct result:

```
In [55]: # correct result:
    ...: B = np.zeros((2,3,5))
    ...: for i in range(2):
    ...:     for j in range(3):
    ...:         B[i,j,:] = A[i,j,Idx[i,j],:]
    ...: 

In [56]: B
Out[56]: 
array([[[ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
        [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.],
        [ 45.,  46.,  47.,  48.,  49.]],

       [[ 60.,  61.,  62.,  63.,  64.],
        [ 90.,  91.,  92.,  93.,  94.],
        [105., 106., 107., 108., 109.]]])
```